# Add Client-Side Validation to Dynamically added HTML elements (on run-time) - MVC Project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, client-side-validation

I'm working on an MVC project where I append html elements dynamically,and I need to add client-side validation to these elements after appending them, Can I do that?! If yes please mention how.

Comment: If you have unobtrusive javascript validation enabled, you should be able to add the appropriate attributes to the fields. If not, listen for the submit event of the form and validate them manually there.

Comment: how can I do that? what attribute can be added to the element to add validation on a specific element appended on run time? please be descriptive.